# Is there a way to share a variable between separate arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, list, arraylist

I want to know if it is possible to store variables in different arrays at the same time, for the purpose of saying "If in this list, do this, if also in this list, also do this." Basically, I want to see some example of shared variables, but when I look it up all I see is mostly networking stuff, which isn't what I'm looking for, or it's not in python and not quite what I'm looking for.

```
Class_skills=[Appraise, Diplomacy, Hide]
Skills_Charisma=[Diplomacy, Bluff]

if i in Class_skills and i in Skills_Charisma:
    RankCalc=Ranks+Player_Attributes.Charisma
```

I'm more looking to see if something like this is possible within python, or if you could emulate the same result in a different way.

Comment: Have you tried the code you have written? It should work given the objects you are storing in the lists are properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

you look like you're very new at Stackoverflow. In general, you should provide the code that you have tried as well as any error messages you've received.

It sounds like your question is a matter of looking at list overlaps in this case, seeing if `diplomacy` is in both the `Skills_Charisma` and `Class_skills` array.

You can use `set` operations to find the intersection of the two.

`list(set(Class_skills) & set(Skills_Charisma))`

You can test with an if statement to see by wrapping a true/false variable around the operation

`bool(list(set(Class_skills) & set(Skills_Charisma)))`

Answer (score 0):

First, seems you are new to stackoverflow, you should read how to make a question, you must provide the code you tried and the errors you received.

anyway you will learn how to type a good question, about this code you provided:

```py
Class_skills=[Appraise, Diplomacy, Hide]
Skills_Charisma=[Diplomacy, Bluff]

if i in Class_skills and i in Skills_Charisma:
    RankCalc=Ranks+Player_Attributes.Charisma
```

Problems in this Code:

- Every object in a cell must be between quotation marks, unless it is defined before, if it is a text then you must use quotation marks
- its not advisable to define things in Big letters in python like `Skills_Charisma` its better to make it `skills_charisma`
- `i` is not in list, so it will not do what is inside the the IF statement, so your code should be something like this

```py
class_skills = ['Appraise', 'Diplomacy', 'Hide']
skills_charisma = ['Diplomacy', 'Bluff']

if 'Diplomacy' in class_skills and 'Diplomacy' in skills_charisma:
    RankCalc=Ranks+Player_Attributes.Charisma
```

Have to mention in python `'Diplomacy'` is different than `'diplomacy'`

Hope this helps